# Debounce for infinite scroll to avoid too many calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

This is a custom directive, tried to using lodash's debounce but doesnt' work. I can remove the debounce but in my network there will be extra 2-4 calls when user scrolled to the bottom of the page. How to solve this?

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('checkBottom', function($document, $window) {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
      $document.bind('scroll', function() {
        if( ($window.innerHeight + $window.scrollY) > $document.innerHeight() - 50) {
          _.debounce(applyFunc, 100 ); // this don't work?

          function applyFunc(){
            scope.$apply(attr.checkBottom);
          }
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.debounce()` creates a function for your later use; it's not something you call to invoke your function. Based on the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce), you'd use it like this:

```
var applyFunc = applyFunc(){
  scope.$apply(attr.checkBottom);
}

var debouncedApplyFunc = _.debounce(applyFunc, 100 );

angular.module('app')
  .directive('checkBottom', function($document, $window) {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
      $document.bind('scroll', function() {
        if( ($window.innerHeight + $window.scrollY) > $document.innerHeight() - 50) {
          debouncedApplyFunc();
        }
      });
    };
  });
```